# Visual Studio Half Circle Progress Bars

Tags: c#, user-interface, progress-bar, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I would like to achieve semi-circle progress bars but I don't have enough experience in visual studio, I did find a circular progress bar Nuget pack that is possible to do full circle but I couldn't find a way to succeed in making half one (even tried to modify source code of CircularProgressBar Nuget pack), is there anyone can give tip or way of achieving that. Thanks.

[What circular progress bar Nuget pack offers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN6X3.png)

[Half-circular progress bar that I am trying to implement on my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9NcK.png)

Comment: considerd using the nuget one and an opacity mask on its lower half?

Comment: it will just hide the lower part of the progress bar its more a workaround than a solution

Comment: is it possible at winform apps ?

Comment: yeah i tried to hide it but when i do more than 1 bar, it gets out of control as in space, also i couldnt find a way to link 2 together like in photoshop

Comment: oh you are using winforms? not wpf? Sorry i have little to no experience in winforms...

Comment: yeah well just tryin to build a test app, i am not experienced at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: SO70211529]

You can subclass and create a custom *semicircle progress* control. All what you need to do is a 180°-based calculation and drawing rather than a 360°.

Derive a new class from the `Label` control and import:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

And encapsulate:

- The key properties of a progress control, `Value`, `Minimum`, and `Maximum`.
- Properties used to draw the progress, track size, track and value colors.
- custom event to notify a subscriber with the value changes.
- The drawing routine which calls the [`Graphics.DrawArc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawarc?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawArc_System_Drawing_Pen_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Single_System_Single_) method to draw both, the track and value arcs.

```cs
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
[DefaultProperty("Value")]
[DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
[ToolboxItem(typeof(ToolboxItem))]
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ProgressBar))]
public class SemiCircleProgress : Label
{
    #region ctor

    public SemiCircleProgress() : base() { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private int _value;
    [DefaultValue(0)]            
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value < Minimum ? Minimum : value > Maximum ? Maximum : value;
                Invalidate();
                OnValueChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    private int _min;
    [DefaultValue(0)]         
    public int Minimum
    {
        get => _min;
        set
        {
            if (_min != value)
            {
                _min = Math.Max(value, 0);
                if (value > _value) _value = value;
                if (value > _max) _max = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _max = 100;            
    [DefaultValue(100)]
    public int Maximum
    {
        get => _max;
        set
        {
            if (_max != value)
            {
                if (value < 1) value = 1;
                if (value < _value) _value = value;
                _max = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _trackSize = 10;
    [DefaultValue(10)]
    public int TrackSize
    {
        get => _trackSize;
        set
        {
            if (_trackSize != value)
            {
                _trackSize = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Color _trackColor = Color.Gray;
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Gray")]
    public Color TrackColor
    {
        get => _trackColor;
        set
        {
            if (_trackColor != value)
            {
                _trackColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Color _valueColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 0);
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255, 128, 0")]
    public Color ValueColor
    {
        get => _valueColor;
        set
        {
            if (_valueColor != value)
            {
                _valueColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _showValue;
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowValue
    {
        get => _showValue;
        set
        {
            if (_showValue != value)
            {
                _showValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
        
    protected override Size DefaultSize => new Size(100, 100);

    #endregion

    #region Paint

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {            
        var g = e.Graphics;            
        var r = new Rectangle(_trackSize, _trackSize,
            Math.Max(_trackSize * 2, Width - _trackSize * 2),
            Math.Max(_trackSize * 2, (Height - _trackSize * 2) * 2));

        using (var pnTrack = new Pen(_trackColor, _trackSize))
        {
            g.Clear(BackColor);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
            g.DrawArc(pnTrack, r, 180, 180);

            if (Value > Minimum)
            {
                var val = (int)Math.Round(180d / Maximum * Value);
                pnTrack.Color = _valueColor;
                // pnTrack.Width -= 2; // uncomment and try...
                g.DrawArc(pnTrack, r, 180, val);
            }
        }

        if (_showValue)
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Value.ToString(), Font, r, ForeColor,
                TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    protected virtual void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e) =>
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e);

    #endregion
}
```

**ToDo :** Hide the not used properties of the base class:

```cs
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public override string Text { get => base.Text; set => base.Text = value; }

[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new Image Image { get; set; }

// ...etc.
```

Comment: yeah it really works, thanks for teaching me more about visual studio. now I know how to create custom controllers etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is may be not the best solution, but you can add a panel over the lower half of the circular progress bar item. Then set the `StartAngle` to 180 and the `Maximum` to the double of your maximum reachable value. Here a little snip of an example (quick and dirty):

[image]

Comment: Yeah this have been my particular solution for now till i find a best way, thanks for the tip